# How to add a click Listener to a table's cell in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, cell, clicklistener

I created a multiselectable table in vaadin, but I can't select only a cell in this table when I click it selects all row.

Is there any way of selecting only a cell of a row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of the question doesn't reflect the actual question inside

> Is there any way of selecting only a cell of a row ?

No. The whole point of a Vaadin table is to reflect *rows* of data in a tabular form. Setting a table to selectable keeps track of the itemIds of the selected rows with the table

You *might* be able to *simulate* selecting cells by using a [`ColumnGenerator`](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.columngenerator) in the table, and adding a listener to the generated component. Removing the listener may be tricky, however.

Alternatively, you may wish to simply generate components in a [`GridLayout`](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.components.gridlayout.html) and keep track of the selected cells yourself.

Ultimately, the approach here really depends upon exacly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I searched ColumnGenerator and wrote a code but it doesn't work.I am trying to do a table(7X24) when I click a cell the other cells in that row will not be selected. if you can give me a short example I will be glad.

Comment: @Hasan : Have you tried making the table setSelectable(false)?

Comment: no I didn't. Codes are here http://www.manashk.com/java/  . Program creates only table and doesn't load content.

Comment: Table reflects the container (like a table model). As you've added no rows/items, there is no content. Look at this post on the Vaadin forum for a working example of a ColumnGenerator https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1602552

Comment: Dear Charles this code doesnt work.type Exception report
message:
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request
exception:
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testwindow.TestWindow cannot be cast to com.vaadin.Application
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleServiceException(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1004)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:548)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: I need your help Charles. I have to finish this work today if not I will do this job with .NET .

Comment: There was no error in the linked code : you've incorrectly configured the web.xml to point to the Window, not the application. Here's a complete Application class, complete with Window, and web.xml https://gist.github.com/3169309 : I really can't help you any more, without actually doing your work for you. You can't have read the Vaadin Documentation : that's what it's there for. It's great. Use it.

Comment: Thank you very very much Charles it works.But I will ask one more simple question I have css file and java file.In java file I attach css like this "table.addStyleName("column-type-value");" but where the css file will be(its directory in eclipse).

Comment: You need to create a custom theme. https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html . I don't use eclipse - but it will be in WEB-INF/VAADIN/themes/your-theme-name/styles.css. This has now turned into a discussion, which is not what SO is all about. Please use the Vaadin Forum (https://vaadin.com/forum) or submit separate questions.

Comment: In regards to whether or not a click listener can be added to a specific cell, this answer is entirely inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. (Your question title and your question details are addressing two different questions.) If you're wondering whether or not you can target a specific cell and add a click listener to it, then yes, of course you can:

```
//initial layout setup
final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
layout.setMargin(true);
setContent(layout);

//Create a table and add a style to allow setting the row height in theme.
final Table table = new Table();
table.addStyleName("components-inside");

//Define the names and data types of columns.
//The "default value" parameter is meaningless here.
table.addContainerProperty("Sum",            Label.class,     null);
table.addContainerProperty("Is Transferred", CheckBox.class,  null);
table.addContainerProperty("Comments",       TextField.class, null);
table.addContainerProperty("Details",        Button.class,    null);

//Add a few items in the table.
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    // Create the fields for the current table row
    Label sumField = new Label(String.format(
                   "Sum is <b>$%04.2f</b><br/><i>(VAT incl.)</i>",
                   new Object[] {new Double(Math.random()*1000)}),
                               Label.CONTENT_XHTML);
    CheckBox transferredField = new CheckBox("is transferred");

    //Multiline text field. This required modifying the 
    //height of the table row.
    TextField commentsField = new TextField();
    //commentsField.setRows(3);

    //The Table item identifier for the row.
    Integer itemId = new Integer(i);

    //Create a button and handle its click. A Button does not
    //know the item it is contained in, so we have to store the
    //item ID as user-defined data.
    Button detailsField = new Button("show details");
    detailsField.setData(itemId);
    detailsField.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // Get the item identifier from the user-defined data.
            Integer iid = (Integer)event.getButton().getData();
            Notification.show("Link " +
                              iid.intValue() + " clicked.");
        } 
    });
    detailsField.addStyleName("link");

    //Create the table row.
    table.addItem(new Object[] {sumField, transferredField,
                                commentsField, detailsField},
                  itemId);
}

//Show just three rows because they are so high.
table.setPageLength(3);

layout.addComponent(table);
```

It might be beneficial to examine [the documentation](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html).